# Run a headless Dart/Flutter callback on receiving a notification in Android

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I am building an app with Flutter that listens to notifications and processes them in a defined way.

I was using the [notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/notifications) package to receive the notifications directly in my Flutter code avoiding the platform implementation, but it didn't work in the background.
A [flutter_background](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background) package allowed the app to remain active while minimized, but it didn't work when the user kills the app or after a long inactivity state.

The [Geofencing example](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124#155c) on writing background isolates seems to be outdated long ago, as many classes in Java are deprecated now.

I tried to create WorkManager tasks on notifications received that would initialize the Flutter engine and run a callback that listens to the messages on the method channel, but the Workers cannot create the FlutterEngine instance, as that can be run only on the main thread.

Is there a way in that I can create a new Flutter Engine to pass the notification data to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a [flutter_background_task](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_task) package which does exactly what I wanted to implement.

It runs the defined Dart callback on the separate isolate that continues executing even if the app is closed by the user (not through the settings, but I think it's the correct behavior) or the device was restarted.

And what was the main request, the notification listener can be started in that callback and then run normally.